# Using the SharePoint 2010 CSOM to Delete a list

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

I am trying to delete a list that contains documents using the SharePoint 2010 CSOM and am using the following code:

```
//find the 'Project Documents' library and delete it
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Documents");
list.DeleteObject();

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

But I always get the exception "This list cannot be deleted".  The list is empty, but still I am not able to delete it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think we have to load the web object first, before you retrieve any lists from it.

Follow the [example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BasicOps_SPListCRUD) (paraphrased) :

```
function deleteList(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.listTitle = 'Project Documents';

    this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    oList.deleteObject();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var result = listTitle + ' deleted.';
    alert(result);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I'm doing above in C#?  I have the context loaded, and I can access the Web using context.Web and then just grab the list using .GetByTitle("Project Documents").

I'm not sure how the .js above is loading anything any different.  I don't have the ability to call .GetLists, but instead just grab the list by title.

Comment: So, I have found that if I go into PowerShell and do $list.AllowDeletion = $True, I can do it.  Apparently when I created the lists programmatically I didn't set that field and it doesn't allow me to delete unless I change that.

Comment: List deletions are set to true for SharePoint generated lists, such as for publishing, workflow, BI features, etc. Thanks for sharing!